# Getting "Lightning: CSS Outside Component" vulnerability in security review

Tags: security-review

As in salesforce security review report, it's mentioned that we should not use float or position: absolute or fixed.

> Uses non-standard positioning (via float or position: absolute or fixed) breaks these guarantees and may interfere with the display of other components

So, Is it good to use slds (.slds-float_left, .slds-is-fixed) class or we should entirely avoid using those styles?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks